# Porting to Android...what is the equivalent of Properties.Settings.Default?

Tags: android, monogame

I'm porting my MonoGame/OpenGL app to Android.  My game uses Properties.Settings.Default to store user preferences.

What is the equivalent of this in Android?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IsolatedStorage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve this in a rather cross-platform way. Xamarin provides [it's own implementation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.IO.IsolatedStorage/) for mobile platforms.